# Forcing iPhone version on an iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, version

is there a quick way of forcing, in Xcode, a universal app to run in its iPhone version on an iPad? By 'quick way' I mean a way that does not involve coding (or too much coding). For instance, in the Summary page of my target app there is a choice button about the Devices; I tried to set that to iPhone (although my app is universal), however on the iPad my app still starts the iPad version.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Change the target device family in the build settings (check screenshot).

[image]

Comment: That's the change I mention in my question about changing the vlau of Devices, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entry in your Info.plist that points to the iPad's interface.  I think it's `NSMainNibFile~ipad` or something similar.

Comment: I've tried that (also in conjunction with the comment above), but unfortunately does not work either...

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it by removing any reference to iPad settings within my app's .plist file and declaring the app as suitable for iPhone devices only. Pretty much what Jonas and Brian mentioned but extended to all references.